# Как по нажатию кнопки заменить элемент с новой информацией на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Надо, что бы по нажатию кнопки введенная информация из правой колонки (название вверху, описание ниже) переходила в левую колонку (заметку) с возможностью закрыть (красный крестик). Подскажите, как можно это сделать с помощью jQuery? (для новичка)

[image: готовый список]
[image: пустой список]

(html)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#bussin-butt')
    .click(function() {
      $('.column-left').remove();
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1000px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#a {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#b {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 261px;
}

.fixed-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.column-left {
  width: 470px;
  height: 136px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
}

.column-left #header {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.column-left #descript {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8993ad;
}

#btn-close {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#column-right {
  width: 470px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  /*bottom: 84px;*/
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.header-input {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8993ad;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#input-h {
  width: 390px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

#input-d {
  width: 390px;
  height: 230px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  resize: none;
}

#bussin-but {
  width: 224px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2174fd;
  border: none;
}

.NewStyle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-container">
  <div id="a">Список дел:
    <div id="b">Добавить новое дело</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-left">
    <div id="header">Пример названия
      <button id="btn-close"><img src="close.png"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="descript">Пример описания</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-container">
  <div id="column-right">
    <div class="header-input">* Название</div>
    <input id="input-h" type="text">
    <div class="header-input">* Описание</div>
    <textarea id="input-d" type="text" name="text"></textarea>
    <button id="bussin-butt">Добавить дело</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот вы на что рассчитываете, что по одной картинке все сразу поймут, как именно решить вашу задачу? Или же, вам нужно, что бы за вас и верстку сделали? И скрипт написали. Приложите к вопросу код, который у вас уже есть, иначе ваш вопрос скорее всего закроют

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз для новичка, тогда немного распишу подробнее, в отличие от других ответов.

Для начала разберём вашу вёрстку и исправим ошибки

```html
<div class="fixed-container">
   <div id="a">Список дел:
    <div id="b">Добавить новое дело</div>
   </div>
   <div class="column-left">
  <!-- <div class="item"> // я оберну карточку, чтобы проще было работать с ней со стороны скрипта. -->
  <div id="header"> <!-- id должен быть уникальным, по этому я заменю его на class -->
      <!-- <span> -->Пример названия<!-- </span> -->
    <button id="btn-close"><img src="close.png"></button> <!-- id должен быть уникальным, по этому я заменю его на class -->
  </div>
  <div id="descript">Пример описания</div> <!-- id должен быть уникальным, по этому я заменю его на class -->
  <!-- </div> -->
   </div>
 </div>
```

---

Далее мы напишем код для создания новой "карточки".

У вас есть два текстовых поля `#input-h`(заголовок) и `#input-d`(описание).
Из них мы должны получить значение и вставить их в пример карточки, а потом, саму карточку, вставить в основной блок `.fixed-container`.
Выше описанное действие мы будем выполнять при нажатии на кнопку `#bussin-butt`

Я бы это оформил следующим образом:

```
let tmp = `<div class="item">
    <div class="header">
      <span></span>
      <button class="btn-close"><img src="close.png"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="descript"></div>
  </div>`; // это вид карточки, его я вынес в отдельную переменную, чтобы было удобнее.

$('#bussin-butt').on('click', function(){ // при нажатии на кнопку
  let h_val = $('#input-h').val().trim(), // из инпута мы получим значение поля, через функцию .val(), а через .trim() удалим лишние пробелы вначале и в конце.
      d_val = $('#input-d').val().trim(); // тоже самое сделаем с полем "описание".

  if(h_val.length > 0 && d_val.length > 0) { // Если поля не пустые, то выполняем следующее
    tmp = $(tmp); // обернём строку, чтобы она стала элементом DOM

    tmp.find('.header > span').text(h_val); // вставим в карточку заголовок
    tmp.find('.descript').text(d_val); // тоже самое проделаем с описанием

    $('.fixed-container .column-left').append(tmp); // далее добавляем новую карточку в основной блок   
  } else { // если пустые, то
    alert('Все поля должны быть заполнены'); // выводим сообщение
    return false;
  }
});
```

---

А теперь поговорим о том, как нам удалить карточку.

И так, в карточке есть кнопка `.btn-close`, при нажатии по которой, нам нужно удалить саму карточку.

Вот так бы сделал я:

```
$('.fixed-container .column-left').on('click', '.btn-close', function(){ // будем использовать делегирование событие нажатия на кнопку
  let parent = $(this).closest('.item'); // При нажатии на кнопку, мы обращаемся к ней и "просим" обратиться к родителю `.item` через функцию .closest()
  parent.remove(); // а теперь удаляем элемент `.item` при помощи функции .remove();
});
```

---

Вот и всё.
Полная демонстрация работы кода:

```js
let tmp = `<div class="item">
    <div class="header">
      <span></span>
      <button class="btn-close"><img src="close.png"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="descript"></div>
  </div>`; // это вид карточки, его я вынес в отдельную переменную, чтобы было удобнее.

$('#bussin-butt').on('click', function() { // при нажатии на кнопку
  let h_val = $('#input-h').val().trim(), // из инпута мы получим значение поля, через функцию .val(), а через .trim() удалим лишние пробелы вначале и в конце.
    d_val = $('#input-d').val().trim(); // тоже самое сделаем с полем "описание".

  if (h_val.length > 0 && d_val.length > 0) { // Если поля не пустые, то выполняем следующее
    tmp = $(tmp); // обернём строку, чтобы она стала элементом DOM

    tmp.find('.header > span').text(h_val); // вставим в карточку заголовок
    tmp.find('.descript').text(d_val); // тоже самое проделаем с описанием

    $('.fixed-container .column-left').append(tmp); // далее добавляем новую карточку в основной блок

  } else { // если пустые, то
    alert('Все поля должны быть заполнены'); // выводим сообщение
    return false;
  }
});

$('.fixed-container .column-left').on('click', '.btn-close', function() { // будем использовать делегирование событие нажатия на кнопку
  let parent = $(this).closest('.item'); // При нажатии на кнопку, мы обращаемся к ней и "просим" обратиться к родителю `.item` через функцию .closest()
  parent.remove(); // а теперь удаляем элемент `.item` при помощи функции .remove();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 1000px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#a {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#b {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 261px;
}

.fixed-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.column-left {
  width: 470px;
  height: 136px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.column-left .item {
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.column-left .header {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.column-left .descript {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8993ad;
}

.btn-close {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#column-right {
  width: 470px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  /*bottom: 84px;*/
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
}

.header-input {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #8993ad;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#input-h {
  width: 390px;
  height: 45px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

#input-d {
  width: 390px;
  height: 230px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  resize: none;
}

#bussin-but {
  width: 224px;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2174fd;
  border: none;
}

.NewStyle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fixed-container">
  <div id="a">Список дел:
    <div id="b">Добавить новое дело</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-left"></div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-container">
  <div id="column-right">
    <div class="header-input">* Название</div>
    <input id="input-h" type="text">
    <div class="header-input">* Описание</div>
    <textarea id="input-d" type="text" name="text"></textarea>
    <button id="bussin-butt">Добавить дело</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Стоит почитать:

HTML и CSS: [атрибут ID](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id) и атрибут [CLASS](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/class), [виды вёрстки](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/06/layout.html).
JQ: [`.val()`](https://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=47), [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), [`.append()`](https://jquery-docs.ru/append/), [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), [`.on()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On), [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) и [делегирование события](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('#bussin-butt').click(function() {
    $("#input-h").val($("#header").text());
    $("#input-d").val($("#descript").text());
    $('.column-left').remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#bussin-butt').on('click', function(){
  let name = $('#input-h').val();
  let desc = $('#input-d').val();
  if(!name){
    alert('Заполните поле Название');
    return false;
  }
  if(!desc){
    alert('Заполните поле Описание');
    return false;
  }
  if($('.column-left-default').length){
    $('.column-left-default').remove();
  }
  var s = '';
  s += '<div class="column-left">';
  s += '<div class="header">';
  s += name;
  s += '<button class="btn-close" onclick="javascript:removeItem(this)"><img src="close.png"></button>';
  s += '</div>';
  s += '<div id="descript">' + desc + '</div>'
  s += '</div>';
  $('.tasks').append(s);
  $('#input-h').val('');
  $('#input-d').val('');
})
function removeItem(el){
  $(el).closest('.column-left').remove();
  if(!$('.column-left').length){
   var s = '';
  s += '<div class="column-left-default">';
  s += '<div class="header">';
  s += 'Пример названия';
  s += '<button class="btn-close"><img src="close.png"></button>';
  s += '</div>';
  s += '<div id="descript">Пример описания</div>'
  s += '</div>';
  $('.tasks').append(s);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#a {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#b {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 261px; 
}

.fixed-container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.column-left,.column-left-default {
    width: 470px;
    height: 136px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
}

    .column-left #header,.column-left-default #header {
        padding: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    }

    .column-left #descript,.column-left-default #descript {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #8993ad;
    }

    #btn-close, .btn-close  {
        border: none;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

#column-right {
    width: 470px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    /*bottom: 84px;*/
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
}

    .header-input {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #8993ad;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    #input-h {
        width: 390px;
        height: 45px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    }

    #input-d {
        width: 390px;
        height: 230px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
        resize: none;
    }

    #bussin-but {
        width: 224px;
        height: 55px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #2174fd;
        border: none;
    }



    .NewStyle {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Список дел</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="fixed-container tasks">
        <div id="a">Список дел:
            <div id="b">Добавить новое дело</div>
        </div>
            <div class="column-left-default">
                <div id="header">Пример названия 
                    <button class="btn-close"><img src="close.png"></button>
                </div>
                <div id="descript">Пример описания</div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed-container">
            <div id="column-right">
                <div class="header-input">* Название</div>
                <input id="input-h" type="text">
                <div class="header-input">* Описание</div>
                <textarea id="input-d" type="text" name="text"></textarea> 
                <button id="bussin-butt">Добавить дело</button>
            </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Надо, что бы по нажатию кнопки введенная информация из правой колонки (название вверху, описание ниже) переходила в левую колонку (заметку) с возможностью закрыть (красный крестик). Подскажите, как можно это сделать с помощью jQuery? (для новичка)

Вот такой вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  // Добавление элемента
  $(".add-task").on("click", function() {
    var tasker = $(this).parent();
    var temp = $("#template") // Клонирование элемента
      .clone()
      // Магия клонирования
      .addClass("gee_" + i)
      .removeAttr("id")
      .appendTo("div.col.displayTask")
      .show();
    // Прочая магия с элементом
    temp.removeClass("task-template");
    // Заполнение
    temp.find(".taskName").text(tasker.find("#taskName").val());
    temp.find(".taskDesc").text(tasker.find("#taskDesc").val());
    temp.removeAttr("id");
    // Счетчик элементов
    i++;
  });
  // Удаление элемента 
  $(".displayTask").on("click", '.remTask', function() {
    $(this).parents('.card').remove()
  });
});
```

```css
.card.task-template {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col displayTask">
      <!-------- Tasks here -------->

    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Featured
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">* Task Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskName" name="taskName" placeholder="Your task name goes here">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">* Task description</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="taskDesc" name="taskDesc" rows="3" placeholder="Your description goes here"></textarea>
            </div>
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary add-task">Add Task</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-------- template  -------->
<div class="card task-template" id="template">
  <div class="card-header">
    <span class="taskName">
      
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remTask">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="taskDesc"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так. Не люблю jquery поэтому на ваниле, по дизайну можно доработать, но логика в порядке.

```js
var form = document.getElementsByClassName('form')[0];
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('cards')[0];
var header = document.getElementsByClassName('form-input')[0];
var disc = document.getElementsByClassName('form-textarea')[0];
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var headerValue = header.value;
  var discValue = disc.value;

  header.value = '';
  disc.value = '';

  if (!headerValue || !discValue) {
    return
  }
  var card = ' <div class="card">\n' +
    '            <h3 class="card-header">' + headerValue + '</h3>\n' +
    '            <div class="card-close"> X </div>\n' +
    '            <div class="card-show"> \\/</div>\n' +
    '            <p class="card-disc"> ' + discValue + '</p>\n' +
    '        </div>'
  card = createElementFromHTML(card);
  card.getElementsByClassName('card-close')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.remove();
    emptyEl()
  });
  card.getElementsByClassName('card-show')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.classList.toggle('card_open');
  });
  cards.insertBefore(card, cards.firstChild);
  emptyEl();
});

function emptyEl() {
  var emptyEl = document.getElementById('empty');
  if (cards.innerHTML.trim()) {
    emptyEl.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    emptyEl.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();
  return div.firstChild;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

main {
  width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list,
.business {
  width: 50%;
}

.list {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.list-header,
.business-header {
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#empty {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card_open {
  min-height: 140px;
}

.card-header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}

.card_open .card-header {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
}

.card-close {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20%;
  color: darkred;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-show {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-disc {
  color: #8993ac;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.card_open .card-disc {
  height: auto;
}

.form {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px 40px 55px 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-input,
.form-textarea {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-input {
  height: 45px;
}

.form-textarea {
  height: 240px;
  resize: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.form-label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8993ac
}

.form-submit {
  width: 225px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #2174fe;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<main>

  <section class="list">
    <h2 class="list-header">Список дел: </h2>
    <div class="cards">
    </div>
    <p id="empty">Список пуст...</p>
  </section>
  <section class="business">
    <h2 class="business-header">Добавить дело</h2>
    <form action="" class="form">
      <label for="form-text" class="form-label">* Название</label>
      <input id="form-text" type="text" class="form-input">
      <label for="form-textarea" class="form-label">* Дело</label>
      <textarea id="form-textarea" class="form-textarea"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Добавить дело" class="form-submit">
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: В консоли в первой строчке JS кода возникает ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", как исправить?